# Sum or product between two given numbers (program in C)

Tags: c

Can somebody help me understand the loopholes in this program?
It has been long that i tried to figure out but got more stuck.
I get

> { warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]    for(N1; N1 <=
>   N2; N1 = (N1 + 2)) }

error when compiling with -wall 
While trying to compile it without -wall the program seems to work but asks for an unnecessary extra input. Help me solve the simple problem. Thank you ery much.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
int N1, N2;

int prod(int N1,int N2);
int soma(int N1, int N2);

int main(){
    printf("Introduz dois numeros N1 e N2\n");
    scanf("%d\n%d\n", &N1, &N2);
    printf("Produto de numeros pares: %d\n", prod(N1,N2));
    printf("Soma de numeros impares: %d\n", soma(N1,N2));
return 0;
}
int prod(int N1,int N2){
    int prod=1;
    if (N1%2 == '0'){
        for(N1; N1 <= N2; N1 = (N1 + 2))
            prod=prod*N1;
    }
    else{
        N1=N1+1;
        for(N1; N1 <= N2; N1 = (N1 + 2))
            prod=prod*N1;
    }
return prod;
}

int soma(int N1, int N2){
    int soma=0;
    if (N1%2 != '0'){
        for(N1; N1 <= N2; N1 = (N1 + 2))
            soma = soma + N1;
    }
    else{
        N1 = N1 + 1;
        for(N1; N1 <= N2; N1 = (N1 + 2)){
            soma = soma + N1;
        }
    }
return soma;
}
```

Comment: There is no need of  \n in scanf

Comment: you havent defined N1 and N2 in your main function ??

Comment: `scanf("%d\n%d\n", &N1, &N2);` --> `scanf("%d%d", &N1, &N2);`.  Better solution, use `fgets()` and then `sscanf(buffer, "%d\n%d\n", &N1, &N2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(N1; N1 <= N2; N1 = (N1 + 2))
     ^
```

The initialization clause has no effect.  There is no assignment here.

Also what is this supposed to mean:

```
if (N1%2 == '0'){
```

Why is N1%2 being compared to a character (whose value is 48) ?

Answer (score 0):

scanf doesnt needs \n

try scanf("%d%d",&N1,&N2);